# How do I post data to an external endpoint from Apache Module?

Tags: apache, module

I'm coding an Apache Module. In the same I'm able to read the request parameters and make some params by processing the request. Now I want to post this data to the external endpoint. How do I do that?

Say I have a data
`char* data = "{clientid:2433211456}";` and I want to post it to a URL `example.com/getPostedData` in async mode, how do I do that?

NOTE : Currently I'm working with plan Apache libs and APXS tool. If I can have some modules on which I can Build the same, please do suggest.

Comment: There's not much provided in httpd to help you with that.

Comment: Agreed that plain apache libs won't provide the same, is there any existing module to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue as follows :

1. I used `curl` to post the request.
2. Installed `libcurl-devel`
3. In the handler method :

   ```
   char* postData="hello=hie";
   CURL *curl;
   curl = curl_easy_init();
   ap_rprintf(r,"Intialized Curl!<br>");
   if(curl) {
     ap_rprintf(r,"Curl Request Posting Started!<br>");
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://google.com/search");
       //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST,1L);
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,postData);
     ap_rprintf(r,"%d",curl_easy_perform(curl));
     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   }
   ```
4. Compiled it as : `apxs -i -a -c mod_example.c -lcurl`
5. Done!!

For more reference on libcurl : http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl

Find my sample module code on github [here](https://github.com/jkdihenkar/Apache-Module-Development/blob/master/05_apachemod_with_curl/mod_example_2.c).